# Magento 2.4.3p1: Porto theme design changes not reflecting

Tags: magento2, theme, porto-theme

I have installed a new instance of Magento 2.4.3p1 and new Porto theme on it. I installed demo of Porto and now I am trying to change the design color from admin but the changes are not reflected on frontend.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the varnish cache. I purged the cache from the server settings and it worked.